# Size of textview in different screens Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm getting sick to find the best away to put the same scale for textView's in different screens density and resolution.
I tried:

- Create different folders, for different density and put "dimensions". Example, folder values-xhdpi and dimensions.xml, values-ldpi and dimensions.xml too. On my code, programmatically i get textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensions(R.id.myDimension);
  In xml, 20sp
- like example above, but put this textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensions(R.id.myDimension);
- Add textAppearence , like textView.setTextAppearance(this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);

But all examples, i got what i wasnt expected, because got texts biggers in biggers density. like in image below

[image: Example]

this happen except if i change my dimension in appropriate xml. But, what structure should i follow?
For an example, in drawbles, people reccomend to use scale like 3:4:6:8, but here i didnt follow a structre.
What are the best pratices ? What people normally do..?
What i want? this..
[image: What i want]

Comment: do you want `20sp` size to be seen equal on various resolution screens?

Comment: have u know multipal device support in android

Comment: DroidDev, im asking if i put 20sp on generic, will be the same in all screens, or i need define for all screens

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a pixel independent unit for your text size. Make dimensions with **sp** unit and load them programmatically.

For supporting multiple screens take a look [in android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

For the sp unit says :

```
Similarly, you should prefer the sp (scale-independent pixel) to define text sizes. 
The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and the system scales the size 
the same as it does for dp.
```

In other words you have two

You have to declare in values file dimension elements. If you don't like the result and you want to declare for each screen category specific text size you have to do the following :

1. You can create a values folder for each dpi. For instance , the folder name can be : values-hdpi , values-xhdpi etc.
2. Inside the values file you can place a dimens.xml file in which you will declare as

   ```
    <resources>
       <dimen name="small_font_size"=10sp></dimen>
       <dimen name="large_font_size"=20sp></dimen>
    </resources>
   ```

Comment: So,should i use different folders and different dimensions?

Comment: You can create a values folder for each dpi. For instance , the folder name can be : values-hdpi , values-xhdpi etc. Inside the values file you can place a dimens.xml file in which you will declare as <dimen name="your_name"=10sp></dimen>

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you. You can create different dimensions files for different screen sizes. For example:

values-sw720dp    10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi and bigger

values-sw600dp    7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi and bigger

values-sw480dp    5.4”  480x854 mdpi and bigger

And take the value in sp for your TextView from your dimensions files.